# How to add GCloud Bucket in ingress manifest?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

It's pretty straightforward to add Bucket to Load Balancer in Google Cloud console. Can I do the same from within ingress manifest (yaml) file?

Cheers

Comment: it is possible via the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333288/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-gcs-redirect-to-index-html-if-no-pat

Comment: it is possible via the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333288/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-gcs-redirect-to-index-html-if-no-pat

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not implemented yet, probably you should use nginx ingress controller for that.

Resources:

- Use [NGINX ingress controller with GCS bucket as a backend](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1809)
- [Setting up Google Cloud with Kubernetes](https://medium.com/google-cloud/setting-up-google-cloud-with-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-and-lets-encrypt-certmanager-bf134b7e406e)
- [Ingress GA, updated KEP](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/1113/commits/8e45fa86fcac9ee4b6a77d4751669eaa84e66f0d?short_path=dd3c6bd#diff-dd3c6bd470f3f350eb1ba698aebe94f6)
- [Use GCE load balancer controller with backend buckets](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/33)