# Kubernetes - Nginx ingress controller - GCS - Redirect to `index.html` if no path in URL

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have this ingress and service created on my Kubernetes cluster

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: google-storage-buckets
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: storage.googleapis.com
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: proxy-assets-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /kinto-static-websites/gatsby/public/$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "storage.googleapis.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: gatsby.vegeta.kintohub.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)$
        backend:
          serviceName: google-storage-buckets
          servicePort: 443
```

However, this works only if I add `index.html` after gatsby.vegeta.kintohub.net.

Same if I go on gatsby.vegeta.kintohub.net/page-2.

How could I make this work plz?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We had a very similar case, gatsby static site on a GCP bucket.

we also tested `try_files` and `index` directives but didn't work.

In our case these hacky `configuration-snippets` did the trick:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: gcp-storage-bucket
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: storage.googleapis.com

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /<BUCKET_NAME>$uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "storage.googleapis.com"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($uri ~ "^/(.*)/$") {
        rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 last;
        proxy_pass  https://storage.googleapis.com;
      }
      if ($uri ~ "^\/$") {
        rewrite ^ /<BUCKET_NAME>/index.html break;
        proxy_pass  https://storage.googleapis.com;
      }
      if ($uri !~ "^(.*)\.(.*)$") {
        rewrite ^ /<BUCKET_NAME>$uri/index.html break;
        proxy_pass  https://storage.googleapis.com;
      }
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: static-site.example.com
  name: static-site.example.com
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: static-site.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: gcp-storage-bucket
            port:
              number: 443
        pathType: Prefix
```

Everything seems to be working fine on our case, except for the 404s

There might be a more efficient way to do this but hopes this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here it's more about your `nginx.conf` and what it thinks it's a default file to try .

The default ingress configuration doesn't have such as thing as always try `index.html`, so you need to add some extra configuration to your [`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) Kubernetes resource. In the case of the nginx ingress controller, you can use the [`configuration-snippet`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation which will add a config under the `location` directive. Something like this should do:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html /index.html;
```

✌️

Comment: Hey @Rico, thanks for your help.
So I added the annotation as advised but I am now getting a 500 for a redirecting loop.

```
2020/08/10 04:13:55 [error] 2326#2326: *26040 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 10.3.0.63, server: gatsby.vegeta.kintohub.net, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "gatsby.vegeta.kintohub.net"
```

Comment: It's back to the 404 I was getting before.

Comment: can you check your nginx.conf? What it looks like? `kubectl cp <nginx-ingress-pod>:nginx.conf nginx.conf. If you remove the annotation and you add it, does it look the same?

Comment: the conf seems fine and the annotations content is being added correctly there when I remove and re-add it. so basically, my nginx controller pick up the config. is there anyway for me to test that out of the box?

Comment: I guess you will have to go back to `try_files`. I'm looking at the nginx docs: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#multiple-index-directives. Try this `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html /index.html; ` to see if removes the loop. How are you hitting your endpoint? from a load balancer?

Comment: With this one, we are back to the 500 (I had tried it yesterday). The ingress controller is behind a load balancer yes, hosting everything on gke. I went as far as trying to create another ingress with the same host and a rewrite rule for `/(.*)/ -> /kinto-static-websites/gatsby/public/$1/index.html` but that makes some external dependencies not working for some reasons.